# Image from field not properly displayed in teaser

Tags: views, theming

On Drupal 10 with Olivero theme, I set image in teaser to be displayed with original size.
I also made sure the image field display is enabled in teaser view.

Still, the image is shown on the left of teaser, as minuscule round image.
It seems teaser display doesn't respect what is set in admin.

How to have image displayed in teaser with specified size and location?

Comment: "Original size" refers to the image URL, i.e. what appears in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag - it doesn't change the CSS that's constraining that image tag, which is probably what you need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `Original size` on display mode, it's refers to the image URL. The CSS of the theme still change the image. You can try create another display or change the CSS, to achive what you want.